# TypeScript d.ts and .js consistency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Using these definitions:
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

So, say, I use angularJS 1.3.14, how to know for sure that there is proper definition for that particular angular version?

Or how to know for sure that DefinitelyTyped *.d.ts file is consistent to its *.js one?

Or If I use older version of AangularJS, how to find proper ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I know it is a proper definition?

You use it and see if you come across a bug. Definitely Typed is open source and accepts issues and contributions so it is easy to remedy any errors in the definitions.

In the case of Angular, the large community will typically result in fewer errors in the definitions as many people are already using them.

> How do I know the `.d.ts` is consistent to its `.js` one?

This is largely the same as above. This is a community endeavour, so there are many people updating type definitions to keep them correct. If you find a problem it is usually simple to solve (the type definition itself usually looks a lot like the API documentation for a library).

> If I use an older version of Angular, how do I find the `.d.ts` file.

You can see the history on GitHub, for example the [angular.d.ts history](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/commits/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts).

You can usually see when the commits go in to update the library versions here.

Comment: so there is no version history, but commit history.. Like in here - by commits: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#tsdjson not as nice as it could be. Not like in package.json, bower.json - the dependencies by version. But now.. this question is more related to 'psd'

Comment: Old versions of popular live do get snapshoted. But we find there to be little community interest in maintaining them. E.g. Angular https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs/legacy it is always best to use latest. You don't get bug fixes in JS or .d.ts otherwise.